# I want to put the star mark as mandatory field in a vf page .I have tried but it is getting on the top of the form.please guide me..?

Tags: salesforce

please help me that  how to put star mark as mandatory field for account number,type ,industry,as mention in the given code.As I already tried but it is coming on the top of the form.please help me.I have already created style class and fields in account object .

Answer (score 0):

In Visualforce if you are using [apex:inputField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) you can use the built in `required` attribute to render the appropriate red bar in the HTML/CSS. Most other input controls also have the same attribute. E.g.

```
<apex:inputText value="{!inputValue}" id="theTextInput" required="true"/>
```

[image: required Visualforce input]

You can also manually include the required elements to get the same effect.

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput" >
    <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
    <apex:inputField value="{!someBinding}" label="The Label"/> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Incidentally, the [Salesforce Stackexchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: I want to put star mark(**) like this  instead of red line .As per our requirement please help me..?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS to change the default 'red Bar' to 'red Asterisk' in front of each required field:

```
.requiredInput .requiredBlock {background-color: transparent; }

.requiredInput .requiredBlock::before { display: block; content: "*"; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold;  color: #c00; margin-left: -4px; margin-top: -2px; }
```

Add the above CSS in your page.

Hope this helps :)